# Change tmp folder for uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, rack

All my uploaded files are temporary stored in the folder `/tmp`.

I would like to change this folder, because the `/tmp` folder is too small.
It does not help me to upload a file and after the upload to move it somewhere else.

I already tried to change `ENV['TMPDIR']`, `ENV['TMP']`, and `ENV['TEMP']` to something else, but my uploaded files (RackMultipart*) are still temporary stored in `/tmp`.

How can I change this behavior? Of course I could mount the `/tmp` to somewhere else, but it would be easier to tell Rails/Rack/Thin/Apache/... where to store the files. I am not using paperclip, etc.

For my server, I use Apache as a proxy balancer to pass the traffic to 4 thin server.

I have a Rails 4 rc1 project using ruby 2.0.

Edit:

```
def create
 file         = params[:sample_file][:files].first
 md5_filename = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(file.original_filename)
 samples      = Sample.where("name in (?)",  params["samples_#{md5_filename}"].map {|exp| exp.split(" (").first}) rescue []
 file_kind    = FileKind.find(params[:file_kind])

 @sample_file                    = SampleFile.new
 @sample_file.file_kind          = file_kind
 @sample_file.samples            = samples
 @sample_file.original_file_name = file.original_filename 
 @sample_file.uploaded_file      = file #TODO: ..
 @sample_file.user               = current_user
 ...
  #many other stuff
 ...

 respond_to do |format|
  if @sample_file.save
    format.html {
      render :json => [@sample_file.to_jq_upload].to_json,
      :content_type => 'text/html',
      :layout => false
    }
    format.json { render json: {files: [@sample_file.to_jq_upload]}, status: :created, location: @sample_file }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: {files: [@sample_file.to_jq_upload]}.to_json, status: :ok}
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: How are you handling the file uploads, you say you aren't using paperclip - is there another gem involved? Post the code that handles the upload of files. At some point are you using a File.write?

Comment: You should set TMP=/other/directory and start the server

Comment: @Matt I use jQuery file upload. When I upload a file, the action :create from the controller :sample_file is used. I do something like `form_for SampleFile.new, html: {multipart: true}`. In the action, I get the file via `params[:sample_file][:files]`

Comment: @bapusethi No, the file is still uploaded into `/tmp`. I tried `TMP=/tmp/yyy && rails s -e production` and `TMP=/tmp/yyy rails s -e production`

Comment: I think its actually TMPDIR and i think this should fix it

Comment: @bapusethi No, TMPDIR does not work. File is still uploaded into `/tmp`

Comment: @Matt I added the code that handles the upload of files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If setting the TMPDIR,TMP,TEMP is not working, it could be that the directory you specified doesn't exist or is not writable. Or $SAFE variable is > 0. The tmp folder is determined using the function Dir.tmpdir (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-tmpdir).

```
class Dir  
  def Dir::tmpdir
    tmp = '.'
    if $SAFE > 0
      tmp = @@systmpdir
    else
      for dir in [ENV['TMPDIR'], ENV['TMP'], ENV['TEMP'], @@systmpdir, '/tmp']
        if dir and stat = File.stat(dir) and stat.directory? and stat.writable?
          tmp = dir
          break
        end rescue nil
      end
      File.expand_path(tmp)
    end
  end
end
```

---

Ruby 2.1

```
def Dir::tmpdir
  if $SAFE > 0
    tmp = @@systmpdir
  else
    tmp = nil
    for dir in [ENV['TMPDIR'], ENV['TMP'], ENV['TEMP'], @@systmpdir, '/tmp', '.']
      next if !dir
      dir = File.expand_path(dir)
      if stat = File.stat(dir) and stat.directory? and stat.writable? and
          (!stat.world_writable? or stat.sticky?)
        tmp = dir
        break
      end rescue nil
    end
    raise ArgumentError, "could not find a temporary directory" if !tmp
    tmp
  end
end
```

So if you're setting the TMP env variables, make sure that the lines below are true

1. $SAFE == 0
2. File.stat("you_dir")
3. File.stat("you_dir").directory?
4. File.stat("you_dir").writable?

Another way to set tempdir is to override the tmpdir in your rails initializer, but obviously this bypasses any directory checking so u gotta make sure it exists/writable

```
class Dir
  def self.tmpdir
    "/your_directory/"
  end
end
```

Comment: I checked 1..4, all of them are true. But the `/tmp` directory did not change. But overwriting the `Dir` class in my initializer works.

Comment: Update: in ruby 2.x series, it adds "." to this, and it additionally checks if the tmp dir is world-writable. Which is generally is, if it's /tmp. So if you are dumping uploads into your Rails.root, this is why!

Answer (score 0):

you should setting the TMP env variables, make sure that the lines below are true

1. $SAFE == 0
2. File.stat("you_dir")
3. File.stat("you_dir").directory?
4. File.stat("you_dir").writable?
5. File.stat("you_dir").sticky? or !File.stat("you_dir").world_writable?

see it [Dir.tmpdir](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d92f09a5eea009fa28cd046e9d0eb698e3d94c5c/lib/bundler/vendor/tmpdir/lib/tmpdir.rb#L27)